# sudoers cmnd_alias to view log files

Tags: sudo

I have this line in my /etc/sudoers file:

```
Cmnd_Alias MSGES = /usr/bin/tail -* /var/log/*, /bin/more * /var/log/*, /bin/cat * /var/log/*, /bin/grep * /var/log/*
```

And I have this:

```
level2  ALL = NOPASSWD: MSGES
```

The object is to allow the level2 user the ability to read log files in the /var/log folder.

But it ain't workin'.  Is this the wrong way to do this?  Do I have to set rights on the file differently?

Here's the rights on /var/log/messages:

```
-rw-r-----  1 root root 174161 2011-10-31 15:30 /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried the following and it functions as expected.

```
Cmnd_Alias MSGES = /usr/bin/tail /var/log/*, /bin/more * /var/log/*, /bin/cat *\
/var/log/*, /bin/grep * /var/log/*
%wheel  ALL = NOPASSWD: MSGES
```

Looks like you are either missing the % for the group or the -* is the problem. 
I try to avoid doing wildcards like that for the command line options. I find it is easier to require them to be the last entries made.

EDIT - I would however suggest that you simply add the users to an admin group and allow that group read access to your log files. Totally your call however.

Comment: It was the wildcard characters.  I took out the * from the more and cat commands and they seem to work.  I need it for the grep and tail commands.  so the new line is:  Cmnd_Alias MSGES = /usr/bin/tail /var/log/*, /usr/bin/tail -* /var/log/*, /bin/more /var/log/*, /bin/cat /var/log/*, /bin/grep * /var/log/*

Comment: The `-*` and `*` aren't a problem if you understand how to use them i.e. if you have them, then there must be something to act upon on the command line.

Comment: The above example is very very dangerous since the wildcard allows the users to specify additional files outside of /var/log. For example allowing the command pattern `/usr/bin/tail /var/log/*` allows the users to run the following: `sudo tail /var/log/../../etc/shadow` or  `sudo tail /var/log/messages /etc/shadow`, both of which would then tail the shadow file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the group permissions of a files in the /var on "adm". After that, add yourself to the group.